# Importing XSLX files into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I just couldn't found answer that would resolve my problem. To be specific what I need: I need to read imported files with `.xslx` extention and to import them in `MySQL` table in appropiate columns.

Here is what I have tried already:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r");
    $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');

        /** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
        include '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


        $inputFileName = $name;  // File to read
        echo 'Loading file ',pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME),' using IOFactory to identify the format<br />';
        try {
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
        }


        echo '<hr />';
        echo "<pre>";
        $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
        print_r($sheetData);

        /* foreach($sheetData as $rec)
        {
            print_r($rec);
        }
         */
    }
```

I forgot to mention that I'm using `PHP/Excel` library for this task, and the above code is trowing this error:

```
 Error loading file "jd.xlsx": Could not open jd.xlsx for reading! File does not exist
```

My table in which I need to store read data has 3 columns, `name`, `surname` and `email`. I require that my users when importing this file have to have following order of values: name, surname and then email in their document(just like structure of table in database). So, if you have some suggestion how to read this file and import it in database I would be very thankful.

Comment: Did you check if the file does exist at the given path? And if PHP has the permission to read it?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried to import file from Desktop, and it still stands there unread  . How to check if PHP has permission to read file?

Comment: try `file_exists` to be absolutely positive php finds your file

Comment: Echo the path of the file and see if it matches the actual file path.

Comment: So the file path appears to be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All comments being totally right, I found that I've made a silly mistake putting this:

```
$inputFileName = $name;
```

Instead of this:

```
$inputFileName = $file;
```

Since is `$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];` and `$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`

Here is what my script outputs now:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => First Name
            [B] => Last Name
            [C] => Nationality
            [D] => Gender
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [A] => jaydeep
            [B] => namera
            [C] => india
            [D] => M
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [A] => harshad
            [B] => fefar
            [C] => india
            [D] => m
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [A] => jd
            [B] => patel
            [C] => ind
            [D] => m
        )

)
```

Thank you all for my insight.